# Error: Could not cast value of type 'Ninjumper.GameScene' to 'SKSpriteNode' when trying to transition

Tags: swift, xcode

(I'm still learning swift, so bear with me). I'm currently trying to code a simple 2D platformer game called "Ninjumper". I have the actual platformer game set up in my GameScene, and I am currently working on creating a main menu with a "Play" button that takes you to the GameScene. All I have on my MenuScene is a color sprite (with texture "playbutton"), that I have programmatically made into a button. When this button is clicked, however, my program crashes with the error shown in the title.

Here is the code inside of my MenuScene:

```
//
//  MenuScene.swift
//  Ninjumper

import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {

    var playButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "playbutton"))

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        addPlayButton()
}

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode = atPoint(location)
            if touchedNode.name == "playButton" {
                // Call the function here.
            let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
            let transition = SKTransition.moveIn(with: .right, duration: 1)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
            }
        }
    }
    func addPlayButton() {
        playButton.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -156)
        playButton.name = "playButton"
        playButton.size = CGSize(width: 280.0, height: 100.0)
        playButton.isHidden = false
        addChild(playButton)
    }
}
```

I want to make it so that when you tap on the button, the scene switches from the MenuScene to the GameScene. However, the code that I currently have results in the error: Could not cast value of type 'Ninjumper.GameScene' to 'SKSpriteNode'. How should I fix this? (Or if you have other ways to make the button switch scenes, let me know)

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: seems to be: self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

Comment: Might you have some other code that treats GameScene as an SKSpriteNode? I’m pretty sure presentScene isn’t itself the issue. Maybe the scene casts self to an SKSpriteNode or something along those lines?

Comment: The only other file that I have would be my GameScene, which is set up as an SKScene. It wouldn't be the line player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode in my didMove(to view: SKView) function do you think?

Comment: That line is suspicious. Try printing the child node’s type before forcefully casting. Check if that type is what you expect

Comment: When I print player, it says it's an SKSpriteNode, just like how I had it defined above my didMove(to view): var player = SKSpriteNode(texture:SKTexture(imageNamed: "ninjastart"))

Comment: It's definitely the player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode that is giving me the problem because when I comment it out, the transition runs perfectly, except my "player" on the view is no longer there

Comment: Did you remember to say `player.name=“player”`?

Comment: Okay, I put that into my didMove(to view) above the line that is giving me an error but it still didn't change anything besides when I print player, it says name: 'player' rather than name: null

Comment: Before you cast and day player = ..., try `print(childNode(withName: “player”))`. Is it nil? Is it Not what you expect? Probably.

Comment: It printed it as Optional(<SKScene> name:'player') ? I don't think this is what I want haha. Is this saying it's a SKScene? And how do I change that?

Comment: Yeah it means it’s getting an SKScene. You have to look at your code and carefully trace who gets what name. Add prints throughout the way to figure out how/when it breaks.

Comment: WAIT I got it to work! On my GameScene, I had GameScene under the Custom Class for the actual sprite itself, player. Such a simple fix for a huge problem haha but thank you so much for helping me identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace the contents of `touchesBegan` with the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}
```

Now create a new function called `touchDown`:

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) { /* ... */ }
```

Inside of our new function:

```
if playButton.contains(pos) {
  if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    let t = SKTransition.moveIn(with: .right, duration: 1)
    self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: t)
  }
}
```

Best of luck! I'll be watching this question, so let me know if you run into the same problem :)